# Display issues on Notebook, but not in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, boot, graphics-card

Since some time, there are some kind of screen Artifacts on my Notebook screen. From the bottom, there are around 50 rows on the screen, which do not Display the appropirate output they should(Aka the entire row has one color).
When it's colder(a bit below of 20°C), more artifacts occur(mainly flickering) in the center of the screen and sometimes, the whole bottom half of the screen becomes unresponsive. This only happens on my internal screen. A screenshot does not include the artifacts.

The Notebook is a **Medion Erazer Deputy P25** (Ryzen 7 5800H / RTX 3060 Mobile Max Q),

BIOS Version is **1.07.03RME1_00021** (Dmidecode says upgradeable but there are no drivers publicly Available)

The only component I added is a **Samsung 980 Pro NVMe SSD**

The curious thing here is, that these artifacts can be found in the BIOS, in Grub, Linux, BSD, Clover Bootloader. When Booting Windows, the Artifacts disappear in the boot process when the screen turns off for a short time. I tried several things like different OS and played around with kernel parameters(but I'm not very experienced with these arguments) but the issue persists.

I simply want to have my Linux(ubuntu and nix) without these artifacts.

Comment: Usually such problems mean that Windows has a better driver.

Comment: Likely a damaged screen or screen connector cable. Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I wanted to do a "yes, but", but then I literally remembered my brother's laptop developed a short in a screen connector ribbon, which he knew nothing about and which then damaged the port on the MB, making the laptop usable only with external screen. So yeah, it looks like mechanical issue.

Comment: But @AcePL why does the Display work like a charm in Windows?

Comment: Drop more details on the notebook - model or if it's a own build components. At the very least BIOS ver, CPU and GPU models. But to answer quickly: you answered yourself - no artifacts on screenshot, which means it's hardware and Windows is compensating somehow.

Comment: From several posts that cross details with this question, it looks like Linux has issues with graphics card drivers. For example Linux is handling badly Nvidia Optimus tech, as well as when in system there are multiple GPUs. Laptops are especially vunlerable to it, because they usually have the outputs to display routed through "on-board" GPU, meaning that in bios there has to be a setting that is either disabled (i.e. Nvidia Optimus) or set to "Discrete Graphics" (or something like that). In other words, this time @harrymc wins over David Postill and me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that it is either a problem with the gpu or the display running the modeset with 144Hz. The Error also exists on Windows, when using 144Hz not the 60Hz as a frame rate. I guess I need to reflash the edid of my display to remove the 144Hz modeset. I was just confused why windows should be able to handle a Display Error which existed in the BIOS.